# This Light effect not showing in Render but shows up in View-port rendering. Affecting both EEVEE and Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

When render in view-port,
[image]

The lights creates this effect on the fuselage(notice the part before wings.). But when I render it out that does not shows up. This is true for both EEVEE and Cycles.
[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: did you make sure in the Outliner that no light was deactivated for render?

Comment: @moonboots Yep, all the lights are enabled in renders.

Comment: Seems quite sure @moonboots is right. Could you add a picture of the outliner with these spots with rendering option shown (the little camera icon)?

Comment: @lemon I don't get what u wrote...outliner(I know what outliner is) and cam icon? If u r asking if their visibility is turned off, NO they're ON for both render and viewport.

Comment: @Ullas, can you extract a significant part of the blend file and upload it here?

Comment: @lemon https://drive.google.com/file/d/12vzILx4y1iF0893tEjFlfGhCXDXP5zs5/view?usp=sharing          U can get the blend file here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final result is hard to see because there is no texture in the shared file and all is pink.

Though, it seems some of the lamps are not activated for rendering.

[image]

To see this icon, use the filter button:

[image]

There is 3 levels of visibility:

- The *eye* icon that corresponds to <kbd>H</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>
- Enable/disable in viewports, the *monitor* icon
- Enable/disable in renders, the *camera* icon

These last two also correspond to the object properties here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mate..The Visibility of lights were ON, So I didn't notice. I have no idea how that got turned off. Thanks